# How to use fusion tables to query data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I have two datasets on fusion tables. One is a points layer (libraries) and the other is a polygon layer (land parcels). How do I design a query using Google Maps/fusion table to figure out this question: how many land parcels are within 1km (for example) of the library?

Also, I've seen some of the like this [one](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/circle_example) where the search distance is pre-defined. Is it possible to design a query that doesn't have predefined search distances? I understand that this task will require the use of javascript (I'm still a beginner), so help in that area would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Google Fusion tables is pretty limited beyond basic use cases. May I suggest bringing your data to CartoDB, this is exactly made to resolve level of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this template and change the drop down radius to a user input - this value will need to be in 1km in order to send the query to the fusion table this uses the Within command.
Fusion Tables also supports the NEAR command.

Please note the Fusion Tables API has changed recently
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide

Submit button can be created as here
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/demo/index.html